# displaymath/split environment with three columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I am writing the following equation:

```
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{split}
  MA &= MAAMB + MACAMB\\
  \Leftrightarrow MA &= (MAAM + MACAM)B\\
  \Leftrightarrow (MAAM + MACAM)^{-1}MA &= B
\end{split}
\end{displaymath}
```

The problem is that I cannot introduce another `&` to separate the equivalent sign (the `\Leftrightarrow`) from the line itself; i.e. to create a distance between the sign and the beginning of the formular. I want that the equivalent signs are aligned similar the the equal signs. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I read somewhere that the `eqnarray` is deprecated? Is this true? Even using an `eqnarray` is not optimal, because the cells are left aligned.

Comment: You could use the `align` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `alignat*` environment:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&                       &MA                    &= MAAMB + MACAMB\\
&  \Leftrightarrow\quad &MA                    &= (MAAM + MACAM)B\\
&  \Leftrightarrow      &(MAAM + MACAM)^{-1}MA &= B
\end{alignat*}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `split`, then you are using `amsmath`, then forget about `displaymath`, use `equation*` instead (then it is eqsy to enable numbering if needed). In your case also change `split` to `aligned` or `alignedat`, that enable support for several alignments, `split` only support one alignment.

It is recommended not to use `eqnarray` as it is flawed and not typographically consistent with the other math constructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `array` inside an equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{lcr}
& MA &= MAAMB + MACAMB\\
  \Leftrightarrow & MA &= (MAAM + MACAM)B\\
  \Leftrightarrow\quad & (MAAM + MACAM)^{-1}MA &= B\\
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you want more spacing, replace `\quad` with `\qquad`

Comment: the spacings on the `=`-s will be wrong

Comment: @daleif ah you're right. I guess `lcl` would be better there...